# Does ErrorCode 0x00000000 in UpdateListItems Response means it success

Tags: list, web-services

After doing an Update opertaion with `UpdateListItems` method of Lists WebServices, I am getting following response

```
<Results xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<Result ID="1,Update">
<ErrorCode>0x00000000</ErrorCode>
<z:row ows_ContentTypeId="0x010100C0161ABF355ED241B6D57E19B121486B" ows_FileLeafRef="1;#test.jpg" ows_Modified_x0020_By="i:0#.w|abscgw\brwas" ows_Created_x0020_By="i:0#.w|abscgw\brwas" ows_File_x0020_Type="jpg" ows__dlc_DocId="TAHTXPJAFTT5-107-1" ....More data goes here.... />
</Result>
</Results>
```

I am new to SharePoint WebServices and not sure if it is success or failure as there is error code node in response.

When I checked for this error code on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvclists.lists.updatelistitems.aspx), I found that it means success.

So does ErrorCode `0x0000000`0 in `UpdateListItems` Response means it has succeeded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `0x00000000` means "no error". You'll find a definitive confirmation in the [Open Specifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd932216(v=office.12).aspx):

> If an operation completes successfully, the value of the ErrorCode
>   MUST be set to 0x00000000.

You'll find the meaning of other codes in the same article.

Comment: How to check if error code is equal to 0x0000000 do one action else do something else